# append data to a google maps business location

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I was curious to know rather google gives the ability to append data to a particular location on their map as long as it resides in your app. for example...

If I wanted to create a rating app that rates stores or restaurants. and customers wanted to look up stores in their location. They will be able to see my data within my app showing the ratings for that particular businesss.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Most certainly. You would need an independent platform that keeps track of your data i.e. ratings, comments, etc. In addition, you would have to manage the entire map yourself i.e. plotting the markers based on user searches and populating the info boxes when they click on a marker (if you need to). Most likely you would have a database that tracks latitude/longitudes of the restaurants. You could even use google itself to retrieve the restaurant info and overlay your own ratings on top of the map when you plot the points.

For instance [here](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html) is a custom info box that you may use to display ratings etc.

One interesting feature I would add to the app is using HTML5's geolocation to automatically detect the user's latitude/longitude.